# Buscar una cadena con _ en sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo que realizar una consulta contra una tabla de una base de datos **SQL Server 2014**, el problema es que tengo que buscar por la cadena _ _ _ **(tres seguidos sin espacios**, lo pongo así porque me lo edita) y como el carácter _ es un wildcard al hacer la búsqueda por `LIKE %___%` no me devuelve los resultados deseados.

Agradeceria si alguien me puede decir como hacer esa búsqueda y que no trate _ _ _ como wildcard sino como tres _ seguidos y solo saque aquellos registros donde el campo tenga _ _ _ en cualquier lugar de la cadena.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar algo que te podría servir para resolver tu problema, es el apartado buscar [carácteres comodín](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_0) en el que comenta que hay dos formas de especificar un carácter que normalmente sería un comodín:

La **primera** sería usar la palabra clave `ESCAPE` para definir un carácter de escape. Cuando el carácter de escape se coloca delante del comodín en un patrón, el comodín se interpreta como un carácter. Ejemplo:

```
WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%/_/_/_%' ESCAPE '/'
```

La **segunda** sería usar corchetes (`[ ]`) para incluir el carácter comodín individualmente. Ejemplo:

```
WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%[_][_][_]%'
```

Comment: muchas gracia, he usado LIKE '%[_][_][_]%' y va perfectamente.

Comment: me alegro que te haya funcionado!